# Does not reducing css file with Tailwind CSS

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-boot, tailwind-css

I trying to use Tailwind for my project. But I can't reduce my css file.

This is structure of my project:

[image: This is structure of my project:]

gulpfile.js:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const babel = require("gulp-babel");
const watch = require('gulp-watch');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const environments = require('gulp-environments');
const uglifycss = require('gulp-uglifycss');
const terser = require('gulp-terser');
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
const purgecss = require('gulp-purgecss');
const production = environments.production;
gulp.task('watch', () => {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: 'localhost:8080',
    });
    gulp.watch(['src/main/resources/**/*.html'], gulp.series('copy-html-and-reload'));
    gulp.watch(['src/main/resources/**/*.css'], gulp.series('copy-css-and-reload'));
    gulp.watch(['src/main/resources/**/*.js'], gulp.series('copy-js-and-reload'));
});
gulp.task('copy-html', () =>
    gulp.src(['src/main/resources/**/*.html'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('target/classes/'))
);
gulp.task('copy-css', () =>
    gulp.src(['src/main/resources/**/*.css'])
        .pipe(postcss())
        .pipe(production(uglifycss()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('target/classes/'))
);
gulp.task('copy-js', () =>
    gulp.src(['src/main/resources/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(production(terser()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('target/classes/'))
);
gulp.task('copy-html-and-reload', gulp.series('copy-html', reload));
gulp.task('copy-css-and-reload', gulp.series('copy-css', reload));
gulp.task('copy-js-and-reload', gulp.series('copy-js', reload));
gulp.task('build', gulp.series('copy-html', 'copy-css', 'copy-js'));
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('watch'));
function reload(done) {
    browserSync.reload();
    done();
}
```

tailwind.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  purge:
      {
        content: ['./src/main/resources/templates/**/*.html']
      },
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "tournament",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "gulp watch",
    "build": "gulp build",
    "build-prod": "NODE_ENV='production' gulp build --env production"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
    "postcss": "^8.3.11",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.4",
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.7",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-environments": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-postcss": "^9.0.1",
    "gulp-purgecss": "^4.0.3",
    "gulp-terser": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-uglifycss": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-watch": "^5.0.1"
  }

}
```

postcss.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {}
    }
}
```

When I run `npm run build-prod` my css file placed in target/classes/static/css/application.css does not reducing. What am I doing wrong? I tried change path to files in gulpfile.css namely from src/main/resources/**/*.css to src/main/resources/static/css/*.css but it did not help. I also changed the path in tailwind.config.js but all in vain.

Comment: Can you compare with https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/taming-thymeleaf-sources to see if you have something different?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Sorry, I can't find any differences. After npm run build-prod I get large-size css file.

Comment: Can you put an example on GitHub for me to have a look?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe yes, but I need about 1 hour for this

Comment: @WimDeblauwe I uploaded files to github, but it's not complete project. Now I can't upload all project. Look at this https://github.com/eugenesmsk/Tournament

Comment: Sorry, but it is not very useful to help you out like this. PurgeCSS would not find any HTML to source to look at. Maybe you can create a small project that has at least enough code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Are you running `npm` directly or via Maven?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe npm running directly. Sorry, I am now far from my laptop on which this project is. I asked my wife to upload it to the github, but she didn't succeed as you see))

I'll upload a full-fledged project tonight

Comment: @WimDeblauwe can you see my project? I added it on Github https://github.com/eugenesmsk/tournament-boot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239501/discussion-between-sbrain-and-wim-deblauwe).

Answer (score 0):

Please check configuration of the PurgeCSS - which is in charge of removing not used CSS code - https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-purgecss#user-content-usage